# After changing constructor parameters in a class, how can I mark any of child classes that need to be updated too?

Tags: php, oop, parameters, constructor, extends

I have a class called `PdfRenderer`

```
class PdfRenderer
{
    function __construct(Fpdi $pdf)
    {
        $this->pdf = $pdf;
    }
}
```

I also have a class `PdfProposalRenderer`

```
class PdfProposalRenderer extends PdfRenderer
{
    function __construct(Fpdi $pdf, array $filename)
    {
        parent::__construct($pdf);
    }
```

}

I need to make a change to the `PdfRenderer` class, by adding a new parameter in the constructor:

```
class PdfRenderer
{
    function __construct(Fpdi $pdf, StreamFactory $streamFactory)
    {
        $this->pdf = $pdf;
        $this->streamFactory = $streamFactory;
    }
}
```

Normally, after this change I search the codebase for any occurrences of "new PdfRenderer", and if there are any, I update instantiation parameters in those places.  That's all that needs to be done, right?  Is there anything else? Usually no?  So that's where I usually stop.

---

Well now, here lies the problem ..  I have a lot of classes, I don't always remember that ...

> In my case `PdfProposalRenderer` extends `PdfRenderer`", so I need to go to `PdfProposalRenderer` and into `construct` method to update the `parent::__construct($pdf)` line to match the change I've made in the parameters of `PdfRenderer`
>
> Also, are there any other classes that extend `PdfRenderer`?  Maybe, I have to check, now that I am aware of this.

But generally I don't run such checks, so this type of change goes missing, until `PdfProposalRenderer` breaks in live code.

**Question**

Is there a way to modify the code in the constructor of `PdfProposalRenderer` or in other places, to where when I update constructor parameters in `PdfRenderer`, it is more painfully obvious that I need to change it in those places too?

For example, is there a way to modify the code in `PdfProposalRenderer's constructor say` new PdfRenderer`?

If not, are there any other ways to check for that change, other than searching the codebase for " extends PdfRenderer" and then checking for any "parent::__construct" lines of code?

Comment: Instead of having to change all the subclasses, could you make the `StreamFactory ` parameter optional? Maybe make it default to `null`. Then you could check for `null` and set `$streamFactory` to a default `StreamFactory`?

Answer (score -1):

Implementing MER's suggestion:

Leaving `PdfProposalRenderer` alone and doing this:

```
class PdfRenderer
{

    function __construct(Fpdi $pdf, StreamFactory $streamFactory = null)
    {
        $this->pdf = $pdf;
        $this->streamFactory = $streamFactory ?? new StreamFactory();
    }
}
```

Also, in `PdfProposalRenderer` I've decided to call out the parent class by name, so instead of

```
parent::__construct($pdf);
```

I used

```
PdfRenderer::__construct($pdf);
```